# How is the B-Spline definition constructed?

Tags: interpolation, spline

I'm trying to understand how the B-Spline definition is constructed. That is, where did the knot vector and the basis functions and their recursive definition come from.

The definition can be seen here:
http://web.cse.ohio-state.edu/~tamaldey/course/784/note5.pdf

There it's also shown how the curve function is got. But not how the reasoning went in building the theory.

Comment: Please look at these notes http://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/ I can provide more discussion later

Comment: For the math behind it, you'll want to read up on dual functionals and blossoms, e.g. http://ftp.cs.wisc.edu/Approx/cagdhand.pdf (in particular p. 12). Depending how much (infinite dimensional) linear algebra you know, this may be more less straightforward to you.

Comment: For a gentler intro that nonetheless is mathematically insightful enough see http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~jean/geomcs-v2.pdf

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell, when people (engineers) started looking at tools to define freeform curves and surfaces, they understood the potential of approximation methods (as opposed to interpolation), which use control points *close to* the curve rather than *exactly on* the curve.

The general principle is to define as set of weighting functions $w_k(t)$ and compute the weighted average of the coordinates of the control points.

$$P=\frac{\sum_{k=0}^n w_k(t)P_k}{\sum_{k=0}^n w_k(t)}.$$

The weight functions $w_k$ are chosen so that they are smooth and dominate the other weights in some part of the range of $t$, so that the curve is "attracted" by the corresponding control point.

Pierre Bézier pioneered this work using the [Bernstein polynomials](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BernsteinPolynomial.html) ($t^k(1-t)^{n-k}$ with a coefficient) as the weights.

[image]

As these polynomials are global (the weights are not zero inside the interval), the control points have long-range influence and the approach isn't practical for a large number of them.

So the next approaches started using piecewise polynomials, nonzero in a subinterval and zero elsewhere. (The situation is similar with Lagrangian interpolation, which shouldn't be used for large $n$, and replaced by piecewise polynomial schemes such as cubic splines.)

[image]

The limits of the polynomial pieces define the knot vector. The weights functions on $n$ points are defined recursively as a linear combination of weight functions of subsets of size $n-1$. (This reminds of the recursive scheme used in the [Neville algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neville%27s_algorithm) for Lagrangian interpolation.)

Comment: Actually, Bézier didn't use Bernstein polynomials. It was only a few years later that Robin Forrest spotted the connection between Bézier's techniques and Bernstein polynomials.